# Удобная реализация js и php

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно использовать много ajax, хочу использовать ооп. Но тут проблема: как из под ajax вызвать функцию в классе?

Comment: Как обычно http://example.com/controller/params

Comment: Т.е. делать отдельный файл, который будет принимать ajax-запросы и в зависимости от параметра запускать функцию?

Comment: Мы же про OOP говорим? Отдельность файлов к OOP никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: > Но тут проблема: как из под ajax вызвать функцию в классе?

Добавить разборщик url, который будет преобразовывать запросы типа

    http://host.org/magic/index

в 

    try { // вообще тут немного другая защита должна быть
        $params = $_GET;
        $controller = new MagicController();
        $response = call_user_func_array(array($controller, 'index'), $params);
    }

или добавить роутер, в котором жестко будут записаны правила таких преобразований.

Самым толковым будет организовать rest api - есть ресурс по адресу /resource, get-запрос получает данные, post - обновляет и т.д.